# Having trouble adding an outdoor outlet by tying into a middle-of-run inside outlet

Tags: electrical

I'm trying to add an outside outlet since my house doesn't have any, and planned to pigtail it to the middle-of-run interior outlet on the adjacent wall. The yellow romex is my new wire that I plan to connect to the outside box. The wires on the left are my line and the other pair are the load that run the outlets down the rest of the wall. Before I took it apart, they were both connected to my outlet.

I know you can't have connections outside of a junction box. Can I make the pigtail inside of the outlet box? And if so, do I then reconnect the original daisy chain line back to the second set of connectors on the receptacle, or would it be better to connect it to the new pigtail that is also feeding my outdoor outlet? Thank you for any help!

[image]

Comment: Pigtails are good inside the box.  The only problem is when people stuff too many wires/cables in one box.  Use wire nuts size for four wires and right gauge.

Comment: And you will use a GFCI outlet outdoors, right?

Comment: I suggest you make your life easier by getting a larger junction box. You'll probably be able to find 21ci blue remodel boxes quite easily. Squishing all the wires into the pictured one might be rough.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as simply as possible, you want to have all 3 cables in the same box with matching wires in wire nuts.  The "pig tail" refers to an extra wire in each wire nut that will go to the interior receptacle.  I usually cut about 6 to 8 inches of extra romex and pull out the wires to make my pigtails.

To make it look professional, get a green screw and also attach a ground wire to the box itself.  The green screws are sold in bulk boxes or sometimes in smaller quantity with a green wire attached.

As noted in comments above, consider getting a deeper or wider old work box too.

Comment: Thank you all for tjhe help, it was very useful!  I agree about the box. Unfortunately I have just been to three hardware stores and checked online, and everyone within 100 miles is sold out of 20cuin old work boxes, so I had to order one on Amazon and will have to wait a few weeks for it to come in. I appreciate it!

Comment: Even a 20 in² isn't going to meet NEC requirements, 6 circuit conductors, +1 for the ground, +2 for the device is 9 conductor count. 9 x 2.25 for #12 = 20.25 (and that doesn't include clamps in the box like the box you show, you would need +2..25in²).